# How do I find merged Records?

Tags: soql, query, account, merge

How do I find the accounts that were merged after the merge operation? Is there any flag being set after the merge process gets completed?  For instance, does any field depict that this particular account is the one of the merged accounts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the immediate aftermath (and a short time thereafter), you can find deleted records with a `MasterRecordId` in the `Recycle Bin`.

```
SELECT MasterRecordId FROM Account
WHERE MasterRecordId != null
ALL ROWS
```

You might be able to use a left inner join but I am unable to confirm currently.

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (/*above query*/)
```

Here's the description of the field from the SOAP API [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm):

> If this object was deleted as the result of a merge, this field contains the ID of the record that was kept. If this object was deleted for any other reason or has not been deleted, the value is null.

---

In terms of how to make use of this field, it should be populated in an `after delete` context. Implementing a trigger handler pattern and error handling are recommended, but omitted here for brevity:

```
trigger Account on Account (after delete)
{
    if (trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if (trigger.isDelete)
        {
            Map<Id, Account> masterRecords = new Map<Id, Account>();
            for (Account record : trigger.old)
            {
                masterRecords.put(
                    record.MasterRecordId,
                    new Account(Id=record.MasterRecordId, Is_Merged__c=true)
                );
            }
            update masterRecords.values();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn something new from you every day.....

Comment: Glad to hear it. :)

Comment: @Adrian.I have a doubt..We wont be able to get masterrecord id if records are being deleted from recycle bin right?What should we do for that?

Comment: @Pri That's why I said you can only rely on this strategy in the immediate aftermath and for a short time thereafter. Eventually, the records are bound to be hard-deleted, either by the system or otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible to override merge Button of standard Page?So that I can Update a field based on that id each time after merge button is clicked?It can also be used for future reference right?

Comment: You could certainly have a checkbox to indicate which records have been merged. Not sure about overrides, but you could set up a polling mechanism so that you check the `Recycle Bin` for records with a `MasterRecordId` periodically and set the checkbox for those master records.

Comment: Thank@Adrian.But in case if a the user deletes the records Manually in between that specified period, what will happen?

Comment: Then you lose your chance. On second thought...an `after delete` trigger should do the trick. Seems like a simpler, more obvious solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45667/discussion-between-pri-and-adrian-larson).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `AccountHistory`, then very easy to do from `AccountHistory` table with out worrying about recycle bin.

```
SELECT AccountId where Field = 'accountMerged'
```